# NumpyBackend' object has no attribute 'tucker'

Tags: python

I have some codes for doing image compression using svd and some more codes for experiments.

So I have the following code for experiment:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
for i,rank in enumerate([2,10,20]):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
    plt.imshow(svd_compression(image1,rank))
    plt.title("rank:%i - compression: %.2f%%" %(rank,svd_compress_ratio(image1,rank)*100))
for i,rank in enumerate([2,10,20]):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+4)
    plt.imshow(svd_compression(image2,rank))
    plt.title("rank:%i - compression: %.2f%%" %(rank,svd_compress_ratio(image2,rank)*100))

plt.show()
```

But I got the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorly/backend/__init__.py in _get_backend_method(key)
     91     try:
---> 92         return getattr(_LOCAL_STATE.backend, key)
     93     except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'NumpyBackend' object has no attribute 'tucker'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorly/backend/__init__.py in _get_backend_method(key)
     92         return getattr(_LOCAL_STATE.backend, key)
     93     except AttributeError:
---> 94         return getattr(_LOADED_BACKENDS[_DEFAULT_BACKEND], key)
     95 
     96 def _get_backend_dir():

AttributeError: 'NumpyBackend' object has no attribute 'tucker'
```

The method for compression is here:

```
!pip install tensorly
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import scipy.sparse.linalg 
import PIL.Image
import tensorly as tl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds

def svd_compression(image, rank):


    unfolded = tl.unfold(image, mode=0)
    u, s, vt = svds(unfolded, rank)
    return tl.fold(np.round(np.dot(u*s,vt),1), 0, image.shape) # need to round to have a color lvl
```